# After Switching to Https, the indexed pages of Search Console Sitemaps has a big drop

Tags: seo, google-search-console, https

We switched to Https on March.15th, at frist everything looked ok, the http site's impressions and clicks drop down, and https site's go up. And I also submitted the Sitemap to Search Console https again on March.14 (In fact, it was March.15, but Search console recorded it as March.14), and it shows 1775 pages are submitted, and 1714 pages are indexed. This lasted 4 days, from March.22, the indexed pages started to drop down to 1559, and it dropped down to 542 on March.24. Now it is March. 28, it still shows only 542 indexed pages.

And I also check this on Http site, it also has the same problem. Its index pages were 1714 (1741 submitted), and it dropped down to 1658 on March.22, and to 582 on March.23, and to 531 on March.26. Now it still shows 531 on March.28.

But it is very strange that the Index Status of Search Console shows http site has 2204 indexed pages, and https site has 269 indexed pages. The http’s indexed pages are much more that the pages submitted.I don't know what make this.

What's wrong with the Sitemap’s indexed numbers and index status? Should I do something to change it? Any answer will be appreciated, and thank you in advance!

PS: I searched site:mysite.com in Google, it shows 2,760 results.

Comment: Two things: When switching from HTTP to HTTPS, assuming you redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, Google will begin to remove HTTP links from the index and SERPs and begin to add HTTPS link. These are two separate sites (technically if not traditionally). Also, to understand the various metrics some, it may help to read this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808

Comment: We have quite a few questions asking this already here, including the one you originally posted on:  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/90813/huge-drop-off-in-google-indexed-pages-after-switching-to-https-should-i-switc  As noted there, you'll need to wait for Google to recrawl these new URLs, which could take weeks.