# Google Search Console reports almost no impressions or clicks after migrating to HTTPS

Tags: google, google-search-console, analytics, statistics, impressions

One of our website has ranked well on Google and showed good Google Impression & Clicks etc.. Around July we implemented SSL for our website and website was now only available over `https://www.example.com`

A proper 301 redirect at root level so all previous link are redirected to HTTPS.  For example:

- `http://www.example.com` | `https://www.example.com`
- `http://www.example.com/page1` | `https://www.example.com/page1`
- `http://www.example.com/page2` | `https://www.example.com/page2`

I kept monitoring website and noticed consistent website traffic on, on the other side I noticed number going down  for Impression & Clicks

When I raised this on forum I was told this is quite normal and it will recover with time but its almost 6-7 months now with no improvement in `Impression & Clicks`.

Do I need to worry about this and how can I get back on normal `Impression & Clicks`

[image]

Comment: Look at the steps outlined by CP3O in this question [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/90813/huge-drop-off-in-google-indexed-pages-after-switching-to-https-should-i-switc?rq=1).

Comment: See also: [Moving from HTTP to HTTPS in Google Search Console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68435/moving-from-http-to-https-in-google-search-console) and although this looks like a Search Console data issue not a ranking drop you might also want to look at [Are drops in Google ranking common after switching to https?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103607/are-drops-in-google-ranking-common-after-switching-to-https)

Answer (score 1):

When you switch to https all your URLs change from http to https.

Google Search Console considers that a different site, it also considers the inclusion of www makes it a different site.

You need to verify that other site with the Google Search Console and look at its data.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect you web site or  include it by http and https both ,with www or non-www but you have to inform Google this change

Comment: Can you explain more?  What are the mechanics of informing Google?

Comment: how can i inform google? i am already doing 301 redirect

Comment: you can configure your server to accept either http or https call? If this is the case you can use protocol relative urls to make your requests use whatever protocol you are already using.

reqUrl = "//www.domainename.com"